Joining two networks
I have two networks. Your bog standard home network, 192.168.1.0/24 being the network range, .254 being the router. The other network is a Raspberry Pi cluster consisting of eight RPi4Bs, PoE HATs and two PoE switches (10.20.30.0/24). The first Pi in the It took me two evenings of struggling to get the USB adapter working and I feel getting the above working is beyond my limited skills.cluster has a USB -> ethernet adapter with the IP address 192.168.1.1 and works fine.
It took me two evenings of struggling to get the USB adapter working and I feel getting the above working is beyond my limited skills.
Can anyone help me create a .yaml file that will allow the 10.20.30.0 network reach the internet through the 192.168.1.1 interface? Failing that, point me to an idiot's guide on how to do it?

The final network organization that you seek is unclear. How are you 10.20.30.0 devices currently getting IP addresses? Why can't they use your bog standard home router? Please edit your question to clarify what you are asking for.

Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

I'm using Ubuntu 24.04. I want all the Pi's on the 10.20.30.0 network to access the internet through the 192.168.1.1 ethernet interface as opposed to wireless. Is it bridging or routing or something?
